# Como mapear valores com pandas DataFrame

Tags: banco-de-dados, python-3.x, pandas, big-data

Estou tentando criar uma nova coluna de dados em formato pandas com base em outros dois dataframes.

Esse primeiro dataset é onde vou buscar os valores:

```
GenPart_pdgID = 
       0   1   2   3   4   5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12     13
0     -4   4  23  23  23  23  23.0 -11.0  11.0  11.0  22.0 -11.0  -4.0 -413.0
1      1  -1  23  23  23 -11  11.0   2.0  21.0  -3.0  11.0 -11.0  11.0  -11.0
2     -1   1  23  21  23  21  23.0  22.0 -13.0  13.0  21.0  21.0   NaN    NaN 
3     -1   1  23  21  23  21  23.0  23.0  23.0 -13.0  13.0  13.0  22.0  -13.0 
4      2  21  23   2  23  23  23.0  23.0  23.0 -11.0  11.0 -11.0  22.0   11.0
...   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...    ...
2734   3  -3  23  23 -11  11  11.0  22.0 -11.0   3.0  -3.0  11.0 -11.0    NaN
2735   1  -1  23  23  23  23  23.0 -13.0  13.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
2736   2  -2  23  23 -11  11  22.0  22.0 -11.0 -11.0  22.0  11.0   NaN    NaN
2737  -2  21  23  -2  23  23 -13.0  13.0   3.0  -1.0   1.0  -1.0  -2.0  221.0
```

O segundo, irá conter duas colunas com os mesmos números de linhas do dataset `GenPart_pdgID`:

```
ele_genIdx = 
         0     1
0      9.0  11.0
1      NaN   NaN
2      NaN   NaN
3      NaN   NaN
4     13.0  11.0
...    ...   ...
2733   NaN   NaN
2734   8.0   6.0
2735   NaN   NaN
2736  -1.0   NaN
2737   NaN   NaN
```

Ou seja, a primeira coluna de `ele_genIdx` vai mapear qual coluna pegar dentro do dataframe `GenPart_pdgID`. Por exemplo, a linha 0 e a linha 4 contém os valores 9 e 13 respectivamente, desse modo, no dataframe `GenPart_pdgID` eu vou pegar a linha 0 dele com a coluna 9 e depois a linha 4 com a coluna 13 e assim por diante.

Obs.: No caso das linhas que contém NaN, eu quero que não retorne nada, já que não contém nenhum valor

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que foi apresentado, parece que o DataFrame não é enorme. Sendo assim, a solução abaixo atenderia

### Carregando bibliotecas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0: [1,2,3], 1:[4,5,6], 2:[7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({0: [0,1,np.nan], 1: [1,2,np.nan]})

print(df1)

   0  1  2
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9


print(df2)

     0    1
0  0.0  1.0
1  1.0  2.0
2  NaN  NaN
```

### Alterando nome das colunas do df2

```
df2.columns = ["idx0", "idx1"]

print(df2)

   idx0  idx1
0   0.0   1.0
1   1.0   2.0
2   NaN   NaN
```

**Nota**: a alteração do nome é para que a coluna não receba sufixos (_x e _y) ao fazer o merge

### Juntando dataframes (merge)

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(df3)

   0  1  2  idx0  idx1
0  1  4  7   0.0   1.0
1  2  5  8   1.0   2.0
2  3  6  9   NaN   NaN
```

### Atribuindo valores

```
df3["valor1"] = df3.apply(lambda row: row[int(row["idx0"])] if not np.isnan(row["idx0"]) else np.nan, axis=1)
df3["valor2"] = df3.apply(lambda row: row[int(row["idx1"])] if not np.isnan(row["idx1"]) else np.nan, axis=1)

print(df3)

   0  1  2  idx0  idx1  valor1  valor2
0  1  4  7   0.0   1.0     1.0     4.0
1  2  5  8   1.0   2.0     5.0     8.0
2  3  6  9   NaN   NaN     NaN     NaN
```

A performance pode ficar comprometida para dataframes muito grandes. Porém, como dito anteriormente, me parece ser um dataframe pequeno com apenas 2737 linhas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. De fato esse dataset é pequeno, mas eu trabalho com uma série de outros datasets com varias entradas. De todo modo, vou tentar usar o que vc mandou. Obrigado mais uma vez

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
col = pd.Series(np.diag(val_df.loc[idx_df[0].dropna().index, idx_df[0].dropna()]))
```

onde `idx_df` corresponde a `ele_genIdx` e `val_df` corresponde a `GenPart_pdgID`.

No caso do seu DataFrame, `print(col)` imprime

```
0    11.0
1    11.0
dtype: float64
```

**Explicação:**

- Na primeira coluna de `idx_df`, remova todos os valores NaN e retorne o índice dos valores restantes:

```
                                  idx_df[0].dropna().index
```

- Na primeira coluna de `idx_df`, remova todos os valores NaN e retorne os valores restantes:

```
                                                            idx_df[0].dropna()
```

- Consulta os valores de `val_df` cuja linha são os índices dos valores não-nulos de `idx_df` e a coluna são os valores não-nulos de `idx_df`:

```
                       val_df.loc[idx_df[0].dropna().index, idx_df[0].dropna()]
```

- Retorne a diagonal principal dos valores obtidos:

```
               np.diag(val_df.loc[idx_df[0].dropna().index, idx_df[0].dropna()])
```

- Transforme em uma série:

```
      pd.Series(np.diag(val_df.loc[idx_df[0].dropna().index, idx_df[0].dropna()]))
```

---

Para evitar calcular `idx_df[0].dropna()` duas vezes, você pode atribuí-lo à uma variável antes de executar o comando:

```
mask = idx_df[0].dropna()
col = pd.Series(np.diag(val_df.loc[mask.index, mask]))
```

---

Opcionalmente, você pode utilizar

```
col = pd.Series(np.diag(val_df.loc[mask.index, mask]), index=mask.index)
```

onde `print(col)` imprimirá

```
0    11.0
4    11.0
dtype: float64
```

ao invés da saída anterior.

Comment: Nossa, que incrível código. Me ajudou muito cara, obrigado mesmo.